# Auto-hiding plasma panel vs visual changes while hidden

Tags: kde, panel, plasma, plasma-5, autohide

I have my main plasma panel hidden by default to remove visual clutter and not get distracted. This works fine.
What would make it even better: if visual changes to the panel would happen even when it's hidden.

Common examples are systray icons from messengers: I get a message and next time I show the panel, the messenger gets a little indicator that there are new messages. Now I jump to my virtual desktop where the messengers are, activate the program, read the message and jump back to my main desktop. Next time I show the panel that includes the messenger icons, it will still have the message indicator, but will quickly remove it, but not before I see it and think I have another message.

The same thing happens for tasks that have been closed, e.g. a copying progress indicator from Krusader (I've set them to pop out and run in their own little windows). It'll finish but will only be removed the next time I activate the panel.

Is there any way to change this behavior? I'd prefer for the panels to always reflect the current state, not the state they were in when they were visible the last time I opened them + a quick transition to the current state.

Comment: Which version of Plasma are you on? If it's a recent one, consider filing a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, I will test whether it changes with the most recent updates and file a bug report / feature request if nobody saves the day by saying the magic word that I need to look for in some config file ;)

Comment: You may also like to ask at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).